# Overwrite variable from routine

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've got this here batch, and I'm trying to get the parent directory to stick.

```
@echo off

SET CWD=

:process
if [%1] == [] goto end
SET MASTER_DIR="%~f1"

rem Change to say, E:\DVD_LIBRARY\Rips
cd /d %MASTER_DIR%
for /R %%D IN (\) DO (

    rem Temporarily change to the subdir, such as E:\DVD_LIBRARY\Rips\SIN_CITY\
    pushd %%D
    for /F "usebackq" %%Z in (`dir /b *.vob 2^>NUL`) DO (
        if exist %%~fZ (

            rem Get this parent directory to store the log file in (eventually)
            CALL :resolve "%%D\.." CWD

            rem Nada.
            echo: %CWD%
        )
    )
    popd
)
shift
goto process

:resolve
SET %2=%~f1
goto :EOF
```

In the `:resolve` routine, I'm getting the value I want.  Back in this block:

```
if exist %%~fZ (
    CALL :resolve "%%D\.." CWD
    echo: %CWD%
)
```

I'm getting nothing.

Any ideas why this isn't sticking, or a better way? I've scoured google and found this technique and some others like it here, but I don't know why the value isn't translating after the `CALL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the `cwd` variable is not set, but you can't echo it the way you tried.
That's because it's expanded when the IF block is parsed.

But you need the expansion after the CALL.
You could solve it with delayed expansion or a CALL-Expansion

```
if exist %%~fZ (
    CALL :resolve "%%D\.." CWD
    call echo: %%CWD%%
)
```

or

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist %%~fZ (
    CALL :resolve "%%D\.." CWD
    echo: !CWD!
)
```